# Open SWF onclick in a DIV with Jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick

For each item in a JSON I create an URL with this code.

```
$('<a>').attr('href',item.link + '?enablejsapi=1&version=3').text(item.title).addClass(domain.replace(/[^a-z]/ig,'_')).appendTo('#sample-feed-block');
```

**How can I force this URL (all SWF) to open the link in a DIV?** Should I add .click(function() ?

Do you think I can call a Jscript function that uses the SWFObject from the Google repository?

```
function loadSWF(url, targetID){

 //Check for existing SWF
 if(isObject(targetID)){

  //replace object/element with a new div
  replaceSwfWithEmptyDiv(targetID);

 }

 //Embed SWF
 if (swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion("9")) {

  var attributes = { data: url, width:"550", height:"400" };
  var params = {};
  var obj = swfobject.createSWF(attributes, params, targetID);

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery SWFObject Plugin](http://sandbox.thewikies.com/temp-swfobject/).

An example how to use it:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('#myFlash').flash('fireworks.swf');
    }
);
</script>

<div id="myFlash">
    The "You don't have flash" message.
    Or any other backup content.
</div>
```

You can find more examples [HERE](http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/examples).